# Using Linq, order objects by some property and select the first 2 objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using a linq query/method chainging I wish to select just the first 2 Point objects in a List ordered by Point.X. How can I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myList.OrderBy(item => item.X).Take(2);
```

Breaking it down:

`OrderBy()` takes a lambda expression which selects the key by which to order. In this case, we want to return the `.X` property on the object. Another example is if we had a `Person` object and wanted to sort by `.FirstName`, the key selector would be `(item => item.FirstName)`.

`Take()` truncates the enumeration to the specified number.